# Disable SPA mode for all links In Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

When an update for my app is released, I would like all users to access the new version asap.

I'm looking for a way to disable all nuxt-links normal internal routing and reload the page to the new url when an update is detected.

Is it possible to change this globally? (without adding code to every nuxt-link):

1. Remove the nuxt-link bahavior from nuxt links that are already <a href links?
2. Update the nuxt-link behavior to do a `location.href =`  instead of the internal navigation (for links on non-a elements or router.push)

Comment: use a service worker to update your app

Comment: I'm looking for a way without interrupting (force reload) or confusing (new version button) the users, so I was thinking of have them refresh as soon as they interact with any nuxt-link

Comment: Please do not nuke the whole Nuxt app on each client side navigation no. Also, not sure why you have such need (and don't want to use a service worker). What do you mean by new version btw? How is it critical? More context is welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could build a wrapper component that you will use instead of `<NuxtLink>` which contains the wanted functionality and passes props and events to the `<NuxtLink>` component otherwise.

Comment: Or just disable JS on the website haha.